# why does CASE WHEN statement group similar variables (SAS PROC SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, case, case-when

When I am using a case when statement like this:

...

```
, case when majcat in (1,2,3,4,5) then "Inpatient"
       when majcat in (3) then "IP-Surgical"
       else "N/A" end as serv_cat
```

the server doesn't keep Inpatient and IP-Surgical separate it groups them together. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here is the full code for context:

```
proc sql;
create table raw_claims_summ as
select pcp_npi
      , pcp_name
      , practice_name
      , rpt_cut_1
      , rpt_cut_2
      , sum(paid)
      , sum(admits)
      , sum(days)
      , sum(units)
      , case when majcat in (1,2,3,4,5) then "Inpatient"
             when majcat in (3) then "IP-Surgical"
             else "N/A" end as serv_cat
 from raw_claims
 group by 1,2,3,4,5,10
 order by 1
;quit;
```

Comment: What result do you want for "3"?

Comment: Do you want to have 2 rows for majcat = 3, for Inpatient and IP-Surgical?

Answer (score 3):

You should remove 3 from the first `when` clause:

```
CASE WHEN majcat IN (1, 2, 4, 5) THEN "Inpatient"
     -- 3 removed here ---^
     WHEN majcat in (3) THEN "IP-Surgical"
     ELSE "N/A" 
END AS serv_cat
```

Comment: Why `WHEN majcat in (3)` instead of `WHEN majcat = 3`?

Comment: @Sami I was keeping OP's form. Using `in` is not wrong, it's just a bit redundant. You could definitely use `=` instead.